# How to handle recursion closing action in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

Let's say you have a method:

```
 Object recursiveMethod() {
     // do some things to an object. 
     Object obj = new Object();

     if (test fails) {
         recursiveMethod(); // do the function again until it fails. 
     }

     System.out.println("Returning object");
     return obj; 
 }
```

What I noticed was that the function gets queued if it fails, and then is popped from the stack after. So, if it fails 5 times it will print:

```
Returning object //success
Returning object //failure
Returning object //failure
Returning object //failure
Returning object //failure
Returning object //failure
```

What is the best way to have the `Returning object` statement print only once?

Here's some of the research that I've done on recursion: http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch17-recur/

Comment: Use a _wrapping_ method that calls you recursive method. Then place the console output into the wrapping method and remove it from the recursive one.

Comment: That would work but I think John Kugelman's explanation is more elegant.

Comment: Put an `else` before the line that prints it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursive call. Otherwise you're calling it but throwing away its return value and instead returning the object that failed the test.

```
if (test fails) {
    return recursiveMethod();
}
```

Be aware that while this may be a good learning exercise, it's not a good idea. Recursion is a poor way to implement retrying because each time you retry the stack grows longer. Eventually it will overflow if you retry too many times. It is much better to use a loop.

```
while (true) {
   //do some things to an object. 
   Object obj = new Object();

   if (test succeeds) {
       System.out.println("Returning object");
       return obj; 
   }
}
```